# How to release the same application with different projects

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, release, google-developers-console

I have an application that has been released on the google play store, but the project is a native android project. I want to recreate the app using flutter and release the update. But when I uploaded it to the Playstore it failed like this

[image]

I have used the same package name, how can I solve it?

Comment: May be you are using different signing key, which used previously for upload apk.

Answer (score 1):

You have to sign your new app, that you recreated using flutter with the exact same key, you used to sign your native app previously.

**Have you lost you previous signing key?**
No problem, google offers support to change your signing key, I recently contacted support for the same issue and the solution is in progress.

Follow these instructions to request an upgrade.

https://cutt.ly/5jkc0TT

[image]

[image]

After submitting the request you'll receive an email guiding you on further steps.